# Change Lua files with C++

Tags: c++, lua

So lets say I have a lua file

```
test.lua
car = { engine = "Test",
        type = "Test"}
```

Now I want to change eg 'engine' to "Test_done", but it has to be persistent.(when I open the file it should also be "Test_done"), so not only runtime.

Ive found Boost:Lib(Filesystem) so far, should that work? Or are there any other solutions?

Comment: So you just want to make a change to a text file in your filesystem, right?

Comment: @iehrlich Well, yes...that's right. I want to write a programm which can change variables inside different lua tables, so yes I only want to make a change to a file.

Comment: Can you overwrite the existing contents with all-new data?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Yes, so I could just use if/ofstream to read all lines, store them into a vector,change them and afterwards rewrite the file? Didnt think of that yesterday since its a Lua file, but I guess it works, if there is no "better" solution.

Comment: "Better" depends on your goals and restrictions. One of those is certainly whether you want to keep the existing Lua code intact. The other is whether this Lua file will be read by a Lua VM or just a text parser.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I do want to read/use the Lua Code with another C++ programm(I use Sol2), so yes the Lua code should stay intact.

Comment: That looks a lot like you want to reinvent `sed`.  Just use `sed -i 's/engine = "Test"/engine = "Test_done"/g' test.lua`.